# Why is my LSTM, stateful network getting 0 accuracy

Tags: keras, numpy, python-3.x

I'm building a NN to predict stock prices but I'm getting an accuracy of 0, I really don't know what hyper parameters to play with anymore but it seems to always get this accuracy

## Build LSTM model

````
model.add(LSTM(
    50, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
    return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch, timesteps, features)))#stateful=True,
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(100, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
               stateful=True, return_sequences=True)) #stateful=True
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))

model.add(layers.LSTM(50, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
               stateful=True, return_sequences=False)) #stateful=True
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))

# Complie model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error",
              metrics=["accuracy", "mse"])

# Train the model
for i in trange(1, desc="Training the fuck out of this model"):
    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=batch, epochs=1,
              shuffle=False)#shuffle=False
    model.reset_states()```

#OUTPUT
```Epoch 1/1

   1/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 1:47:06 - loss: 0.0318 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0318
   2/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 56:57 - loss: 0.0246 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0246  
   3/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 40:29 - loss: 0.0174 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0174
   4/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 32:15 - loss: 0.0135 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0135
   5/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 27:18 - loss: 0.0141 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0141
   6/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 24:00 - loss: 0.0150 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0150
   7/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 21:40 - loss: 0.0142 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0142
   8/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 19:48 - loss: 0.0125 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0125
   9/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 18:26 - loss: 0.0115 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0115
  10/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 17:20 - loss: 0.0108 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0108
  11/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 16:27 - loss: 0.0100 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0100
  12/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 15:42 - loss: 0.0094 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0094
  13/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 15:08 - loss: 0.0089 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0089
  14/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 14:32 - loss: 0.0083 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0083
  15/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 14:06 - loss: 0.0080 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0080
  16/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 13:39 - loss: 0.0076 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0076
  17/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 13:17 - loss: 0.0072 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0072
  18/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 12:58 - loss: 0.0068 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0068
  19/2918 [..............................] - ETA: 12:40 - loss: 0.0065 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0065```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine. Also, the model is working as you can see the loss is continuously decreasing.

The thing is, this is a regression problem and `accuracy` is used for classification tasks. It just calculates how often predictions match labels by comparing if the classes are the same. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy) for more details on how it works. So, just remove `accuracy` from your `metrics` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, makes a whole lot more sence